# DataGridComboBox Column and binding in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have an application which uses a `DataGrid` control Which has a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` defined in XAML. Now I have a requirement in which I want to create the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` and its binding in code behind.

My XAML is :

```
<my:DataGrid.Columns>
   <my:DataGridComboBoxColumn 
      Width="100" 
      Header="Product Code" 
      SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Product_Id,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
      SelectedValuePath="Product_Id" 
      DisplayMemberPath="Product_Code">
      <my:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=ProductList}"/>
         </Style>
      </my:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
      <my:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource"  Value="{Binding Path=ProductList}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
                  <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
               </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </my:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
   </my:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
</my:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Now I want to do the `DataGridComboBox` column above and its binding in code how to accomplish this?

Comment: This is *not* a website that you can use to get your code written for you... please show what you have tried. Otherwise, please look on MSDN for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

where `datagrid` is the instance your DataGrid.

```
        datagrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridComboBoxColumn()
        {
            Width = 100,
            Header = "Product Code",
            SelectedValuePath="Product_Id",
            DisplayMemberPath="Product_Code",
            SelectedValueBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding()
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath("Product_Id"), 
                UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged, 
                ValidatesOnDataErrors = true
            }
        });
```

follow these things for the rest of the things...

Comment: But my main problem with combobox itemsSource binding how do i bind it to the property of my viewModel